# how Insert data use execute immediate in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using oracle 10g . I want execute dynamic insert query into that fields are select from another query in procedure .

```
    sql_stmt := 'INSERT INTO tt_causalvarien VALUES(:breakdate, :batch, :procode, :rpcaption, :rvminmaxs, :rpvalue)';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt USING  select brkngdte,batch,prdtcode,'RP1','S',getminmax('qtyadded','vttrcwfdetatdryer','S','prdcode','PRC002','vttrcwfaddatdryer') Test_Sample
              from skybluem.VMtrcwfhdailyplansheet;
```

Can you please help ? And can you give me tips how to write this type of queries.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if i got your example right by what is static and what is dynamic, but in general for that purpose you don't need `execute immediate`, you can just insert into a table with a select from:

```
  INSERT INTO tt_causalvarien 
SELECT brkngdte,batch,prdtcode,'RP1','S',getminmax('qtyadded','vttrcwfdetatdryer','S','prdcode','PRC002','vttrcwfaddatdryer') 
FROM skybluem.VMtrcwfhdailyplansheet;
```

Comment: Hi evilive , Insert query is static and select query was dynamic

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic queries are used to build SQL statement at runtime. As you have access to the whole statement as *text*, you have much more flexibility than by using SQL statements that are known at compilation time. See [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm#24463).

Broadly speaking, you need dynamic SQL if you need to change something else than a value in your SQL query.

Given your example, you have 3 options:

1. As explained by @evilive in her own answer, given your example, you can rewrite your statement as a simple `INSERT ... SELECT`. Please note this does not necessarily insert *one* row. Depending your data/exact query, this can trigger the insert of *several* rows. Or of *no* rows at all.
2. You can use PL/SQL `SELECT .. INTO` and data substitution (
          don't forget to declare as needed the variables:
                   breakdate, batch, procode, 
                   rpcaption, rvminmaxs,
                   rpvalue)

   ```
      select "brkngdte", "batch", "prdtcode", 'RP1', 'S',
             getminmax('qtyadded', 'vttrcwfdetatdryer', 'S', 'prdcode', 'PRC002', 'vttrcwfaddatdryer') Test_Sample
      into breakdate, batch, procode, rpcaption, rvminmaxs,
             rpvalue
      from skybluem.VMtrcwfhdailyplansheet;

      INSERT INTO tt_causalvarien VALUES(breakdate, batch, procode, rpcaption, rvminmaxs, rpvalue);

      This will trigger an exception if the `select` statement returns no row or several rows.
   ```
3. If you really need to build the `INSERT` query dynamically (say because the name of the table in only known at runtime):

   ```
      sql_stmt := 'INSERT INTO ' || some_table || ' VALUES(:breakdate, :batch, :procode, :rpcaption, :rvminmaxs, :rpvalue)';
      --                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      --                   *this* require dynamic SQL

      select "brkngdte", "batch", "prdtcode", 'RP1', 'S',
             getminmax('qtyadded', 'vttrcwfdetatdryer', 'S', 'prdcode', 'PRC002', 'vttrcwfaddatdryer') Test_Sample
      into breakdate, batch, procode, rpcaption, rvminmaxs,
             rpvalue
      from skybluem.VMtrcwfhdailyplansheet;

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt USING breakdate, batch, procode, rpcaption, rvminmaxs, rpvalue;
   ```

   Once again, as you are using `SELECT ... INTO` the PL/SQL runtime ensure that *one and only one row* will be selected. And will trigger an exception if this is not the case.

---

In addition, as per OP request, if the `SELECT` query is *dynamic* too, you might use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ... INTO` to fetch the row data. After that, depending your use case, you can go either for a `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ... USING` of a plain `INSERT` statement. Here is a "fully dynamic" example:

```
   sel_stmt := 'select "brkngdte", "batch" ... from skybluem.VMtrcwfhdailyplansheet';
   sql_stmt := 'INSERT INTO ' || some_table || ' VALUES(:breakdate, :batch, :procode, :rpcaption, :rvminmaxs, :rpvalue)';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sel_stmt 
           INTO breakdate, batch, procode, rpcaption, rvminmaxs, rpvalue;

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt 
           USING breakdate, batch, procode, rpcaption, rvminmaxs, rpvalue;
```

Please see the [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE reference documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm) for the various supported syntax and [Using the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE Statement in PL/SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm#i13130) for some introduction material.

Comment: Hi Sylvain ,  This select query also Dynamic query  ''select "brkngdte", "batch", "prdtcode", 'RP1', 'S',
          getminmax('qtyadded', 'vttrcwfdetatdryer', 'S', 'prdcode', 'PRC002', 'vttrcwfaddatdryer') Test_Sample
   into breakdate, batch, procode, rpcaption, rvminmaxs,
          rpvalue
   from skybluem.VMtrcwfhdailyplansheet; '' wat we do?

Comment: @Dharmaraj `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` support both an `INTO` clause to fetch (output) data and a `USING` clause to bind (input) data. I've edited my answer to provide some additional example and pointers to the relevant documentation. I hope this helps you.